# Database design, stores over 10 images paths in a single field

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

*Hello,*

*My Original design:*

```
create table product (
product_id
... ...
);

create table image (
image_id,
path,
product_id
... ...
);
```

*However, my colleague thinks creating a single table is enough*

```
create table product (
product_id,
images_paths,
... ...
);
```

*images_paths, therefore stores multiple images' paths. For instance, 01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg ... ...*

*Which way is better?*

Comment: SQL has data structures *designed* for storing multiple values (tables) and tool for *optimizing* access to the values in those data structures (indexes). So why would someone *ignore* those and store everything in a string, a data type *not* specifically designed for storing multiple values.

Comment: Don't let your colleague near databases, or software development in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single table is most likely the worse off option.  The reason for this is that it represents unnormalized data.  In the single table design, you are storing several points of data in a single column.  This would make it difficult to tease apart image paths individually in a query.

The two table approach is on the right track, but the correct solution here might actually be a *three* table approach:

```
product (product_id, ...)
image (image_id, path, ...)
product_image (product_id, image_id)
```

The `product` table remains essentially as is.  The `image` table has been refactored such that each row just records a single image and its path.  New to the schema is a *junction* table `product_image` which keeps track of which images are associated with which products.

This approach minimizes the duplication of data, and with proper indices setup the joins should perform reasonably well.

Comment: Surely the decision on two/three tables depends a lot on whether images are unique to products or shared, information not readily provided to us in the OPs question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Agreed.  I still vote against the one table solution for the reasons I gave.  I can readily imagine that an image might be shared across more than one product.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen   Thank you